# Trouble getting the timestamp attributes for Active Record

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

So I'm trying to get the `updated at` attribute for my database object, but it's not working. I can get the other attributes but not the `updated_at` or `created_at` attributes. I'm also noticing that I can't get the `id` attribute as well. It seems as if anything I haven't declared in my `Pocket.new` does not exist. Here's my code:

By the way, I'm not using rails. I'm using `sinatra-activerecord` and `sinatra`.

### Model

```
class Pocket < ActiveRecord::Base     
    def retrieve(consumer_key) 
        url = "get/"
        pocket_url = join_url(url)
        # time = Time.now.to_i
        token = self.token
        puts consumer_key
        puts self 
        puts time = self.updated_at  #.to_i this is where it happens.
        options = {
            :access_token => token,
            :consumer_key => consumer_key, 
            :since => (time if defined? time)
        }

        hello = RestClient.post pocket_url, options
        # JSON.parse(hello)
    end
```

### Controller

```
get '/auth/pocket/callback' do
      […]

      pocket = Pocket.new(token: @token, user: @user)
```

### DB migration

```
class CreatePocket < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :pockets do |t|
        t.string :user
        t.string :token
        t.timestamps    
    end 
  end

  def down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Comment: My guess is that your ActiveRecord configuration is wrong and/or not being loaded correctly. id, created_at, and updated_at are attr_accessor that ActiveRecord adds based on the associated table.

Can you post the relevant bits where you load ActiveRecord?

Comment: Just to clarify -- are you seeing an exception, or just getting nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id`, `created_at`, and `updated_at` are going to be `nil` for un-persisted objects, which is what you have by just calling `.new` and not saving the object yet.

Those attributes will be sent as soon as you call `.save` (assuming there are no validation errors).

Actually that isn't 100% true. `updated_at` will not be set on the first create / save, but it will be set on subsequent saves.

Comment: This is true, but it seems like he's getting an exception, not a nil.